# Installing boost in debian (for Codeblocks)

Tags: c++, linux, boost, debian, codeblocks

I'm currently working on a project that I've been assigned. I'm going to program a gateway (also known as a router). I have a virtual setup with 3 virtual machines (3 debian 7.1 devices).

The first one represents the gateway (the router) and the two other represents two clients (computers) who are going to transmit information between each other, through the gateway. The two clients have static IP's for the virtual representation.

I have installed Code::Blocks for Debian on the gateway, and I'm planning to program this all in C++ (or C). I have not made up my mind entirely, but I plan to use C++ as for now.

I've searched around a little to find out how to create sockets in C++ so I can start getting a grip on stuff and start looking on some packets which I will send from Client1. There's a lot of different libraries it seems, but Boost is pretty much preferred as far as I've found. I can't quite get a grip on how to install boost for Debian and use it in code blocks, so if someone could explain it low tech wise for me..?

I've downloaded the most recent version of Boost and extracted it somewhere on the gateway. How do I install it and make it work for Codeblocks?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Integrating Boost in to Code::Blocks is beyond my ken, but here is how I acquire and install Boost under linux.  This is particularly for version 1.54.0, but you can adjust for whatever version you prefer:

```
mkdir -p ~/dev/boost
cd ~/dev/boost
wget http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost/1.54.0/boost_1_54_0.tar.gz
tar -zxf boost_1_54_0.tar.gz
cd boost_1_54_0
sudo ./bootstrap.sh
sudo ./b2 install
sudo ln -s /usr/local/include/boost_1_54_0/ /usr/local/include/boost
```

Comment: I get an error at the "tar -zxf boost_1_54_0.tar.gz" step.

"The function open failed: No such file or directory"

Comment: @Zeliax:  The previous `wget` step must have failed.  Did `wget` download a file to your drive?

Comment: As far as I know it did, but I think step 2 failed.. (No such path or directory)

Comment: @Zeliax: Do you see the actual file on your hard drive?

Comment: Nopes, but I think I found the solution.

Comment: Yes I did. I'll write the solution for everyone else to see when I get time ;)

Answer (score 0):

http://tuxarena.blogspot.in/2009/01/how-to-compile-and-install-codeblocks.html

The above link would be helpful.

Thanks & Regards,
Alok Thaker

Comment: Thanks. But the "guide" failed at some point and proved not to be very helpful after all.

Comment: Edit: Btw, this guide is nothing like the guide I would need. I have codeblocks installed and it works fine. My problem at the moment is boost only..